# Como manter a janela aberta em Python Kivy?

Tags: python, python-kivy

Estou aprendendo a biblioteca Kivy, do Python. O código não está a dar erros, mas a janela abre e fecha imediatamente. Como posso fazer com que a janela se mantenha aberta?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kivy.require('1.9.1')

class PrimeiroApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World, Kivy!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PrimeiroApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Texto(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Texto,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = 'Label'
    
class NameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Texto()

NameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


def build(): # retornar o gratico 3
  return Label(text="Label") # ao iniciada retornara a classe de label


janela = App() # instancia de App 1
janela.build  = build # associando build definida em App a função build criada 3..
janela.run() # iniciando o app:  2
```

Primeiramente foi iniciada uma variável chamada janela e foi atribuída a ela a classe App
depois foi iniciada o app com a função run().
A classe App tem a função build interna e foi vinculada a função build criada que retorna uma classe Label. usando apenas função.